# How to reset data of inline itemrenderer of spark datagrid view in flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am new to flex 4. I am having a datagrid view with inline itemrenderers. I want to enter the data into that components in case if the entered data is wrong i need to reset that row.how can i do that using flex 4

```
<s:DataGrid  width="703" height="285" >
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn width="150" dataField="dataField1" headerText="Category" rendererIsEditable="true">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <mx:VBox paddingBottom="5" paddingTop="10" >
                            <s:ComboBox width="152" chromeColor="#248895" />
                                </mx:VBox>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn width="200" dataField="dataField2" headerText="Product Name">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <mx:VBox paddingBottom="5" paddingTop="10" >
                            <s:ComboBox  width="200" chromeColor="#248895" />
                                </mx:VBox>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn width="80" dataField="dataField3" headerText="AvailableStock">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <mx:VBox paddingBottom="5" paddingTop="10" >
                            <s:TextInput width="80"/>
                                </mx:VBox>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>



        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom item editor with a text input ..
Do the validations on the textInput.text
If invalid reset the edit to a custom message ..
or dispatch the ESC key event ..that resets the grid or edited item to its previous state.